# OTP or Captcha or reCAPTHCA

Tags: ddos

I am developing a web application in Java. I need to protect my application from Denial of Service attack. What would be a better solution OTP or Captcha or  reCAPTHCA or is there any other solutions.

Comment: You might be confusing automated and brute-force attacks with denial of service. DOS can be a side effect of brute-force attacks but DOS can also happen independently by someone who simply sends loads of requests.

Answer (score 3):

None of these technologies will protect you from (D)DoS attacks. They will only (try to) prevent bots from accessing (a certain part of) your application. A (D)DoS attack could make the page of your Captcha unavailable, and you would have the same problem.

(D)DoS attacks can, for example, be prevented by adding advanced firewall rules, or by using paid services (e.g. Cloudflare). I suggest you search the web on how to protect yourself against (D)DoS attacks.